# Mechanically alter frequency of audio from a speaker

Tags: speakers, sound

I am a programmer and my knowledge with hardware is very limited. So, bear with me with the question I have here. It may also be a dumb question.

**in short:** Can I apply some mechanical changes on a speaker so that the frequency of sound coming out of the speaker can be altered?

**longer story** We have a system of speakers connected through the same line. They all play the same sound repeatedly. The sound is also created from a repetition of a smaller audio signal of ultrasound nature. For research purpose it would have been better if the audio played from the speakers were different in the way they are constructed in the frequency domain. However because of infrastructure limitations I can't have every speaker play its own sound. So I was thinking what changes I could apply on the speaker itself so that the sound finally coming out of the speaker is at all even a little different in the frequency domain. I just want to introduce noise basically.

I would really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking. Are you trying to *shift* the frequency of a signal? *Attenuate* certain frequencies selectively (i.e. with a filter)? Add noise to individual speakers on top of the same signal sent to all of them? A sketch or graph of the spectrum of the signal sent to all speakers, and what you want to see at individual speakers, would be very helpful.

Comment: @nanofarad thanks for your reply. Maybe I have to specify it better. What I mean is apply the change individually for the speakers, so that the sound from the speakers are a little bit different from one another. For example if all speakers are playing 18KHz I want to make speaker A play 18.5KHz (or anything) and speaker B 19KHz. I am wondering if I can achieve this mechanically.

Comment: No, you can't achieve this mechanically. This is an electrical site.

Comment: @Andyaka ok thanks for your comment. FYI I only just want to introduce noise that can be reflected in the frequency domain of the audio that is output. Just only some noise. So, for instance damping and like that could have effect on the frequency domain, no?

Comment: You can damage your speaker so it produces more distortion. Then if you excite it at 18 kHz you can get a response at 36 kHz and 52 kHz (and further harmonics beyond the audible range). But if you excite it with a pure tone at 18 kHz, you're not going to get a response at 19 kHz. That's basic systems theory in ME or EE.

Comment: Damaged speakers sound different from good ones. But usually that is undesirable. You can try throwing sand inside the voicecoil. I am pretty sure that speaker will never sound right after that.

Comment: @mkeith, if you're Link Wray you puncture the diaphragm with a pencil to get that fuzzy sound.

Comment: Temporarily you could move the speaker towards or away from the listener, and exploit the Doppler effect. To shift 18kHz by 3% you would need to move it at Mach 0.03 or about 20-25mph. For carefully timed short bursts, you could mount each speaker on a fairground carousel. (This is the sort of answer generated by absurd restrictions eliminating the obvious solution of an audio channel each. TL/DR : rethink that)

Comment: @Andyaka, you forgot about [Leslie speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_speaker).

Comment: @Transistor the op needs to specify that they are happy with the continuous (non-static) frequency modulation that a Leslie speaker produces.

Answer (score 2):

It would be difficult to produce 18kHz with speaker alone. However, well designed [Resonance Chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonance_chamber) can produce higher pitch harmonics efficiently.

Acoustic Resonator is discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_resonance) as well:

> The resonance of a tube of air is related to the length of the tube,
> its shape, and whether it has closed or open ends. Many musical
> instruments resemble tubes that are conical or cylindrical (see bore).
> A pipe that is closed at one end and open at the other is said to be
> stopped or closed while an open pipe is open at both ends.

[image]